# Rails: I don't get any error messages in my log file only 500 page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am running a rails 3 app under ruby 1.9.3 with puma.
When open localhost:3000 there is always the 500 page shown.
I've tried to set binding.pry and log messages across the files (e.g. ApplicationController), but it seems they are never reached.
I changed the root path to a controller that does not exist, still no log messages.
So it seems like the route is never reached as well.
I ve looked into the rails log, puma log, rack log but nothing is shown.
Any idea how to get appropriate error messages?
Please help, I am so frustrated, looking for the erros for days.

I should add that I can see requests in my log:
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-03-30 00:09:24 +0200
But that's it. Rails.logger isnt even logging most of the time.

config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
 config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
is also set.

I've tried RACK_ENV=development puma config.ru

Comment: can you check in your rails app is RAILS_ENV is set to development as well?

Comment: Yes, I have already checked it:
    Puma 1.6.3 starting...
    * Min threads: 0, max threads: 16
    * Environment: development
    * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:9292
Beside that I add Rails.env to my logger. It printed "development"

Comment: Is the 500 error page you're getting dynamically generated by Rails or is it the 500.html in the public/ folder?

Comment: It's the public/500.html